# How can I create order in Pine Script with specific settings according to current price and specific time

Tags: tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, etrade-api

hello i want to creat a simple pin scripte that make me place an order when the value of the current candle are supperior than start value (+40 for example ) and close at the final of candle

```
//@version=5
strategy("test", "test", true)
//variable declartions
plotPivots = true
pivotLookup = 5
hih = ta.pivothigh(high, pivotLookup, pivotLookup)
lol = ta.pivotlow (low , pivotLookup, pivotLookup)
top = ta.valuewhen(hih, high[pivotLookup], 0)
bottom = ta.valuewhen(lol, low [pivotLookup], 0)
plot(top, offset=-pivotLookup, linewidth=2, color=(top != top[1] ? na : (plotPivots ? color.silver : na)), title="pivotTop")
plot(bottom, offset=-pivotLookup, linewidth=2, color=(bottom != bottom[1] ? na : (plotPivots ? color.silver : na)), title="pivotBottom")

strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long, stop=top, comment="BUY STOP", alert_message="BUY")
strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short, stop=bottom,  comment="SELL STOP", alert_message="SELL")
```

and thanx a lot i'm new on pin script